# Error 127 when trying to install ms-sys

Tags: fedora

I just installed Fedora 20 and am trying to install ms-sys. However, when I do "make", I am presented with the following error:

```
"cc -O2 -ansi -pedantic -Wall -c -I inc -D PACKAGE=\"ms-sys\" -D LOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" -idirafter include-fallback -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -o obj/fat32fd.o src/fat32fd.c
make: cc: Command not found
make: *** [obj/fat32fd.o] Error 127"
```

I have tried to install gettext as many believes to be the solution to error 127, but it is already installed according to yum.

Comment: Please don't answer the question within the question. If you don't want to accept my answer, post your own answer separately and accept that.

Comment: I did not see your answer when I wrote the edit.

Comment: That's fine. I mainly wanted to point out that Stack Exchange lets you post an answer to your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have a C compiler installed. Say:

```
# yum install gcc
```

as root to fix this.

If GCC is *supposed* to be installed, say `yum reinstall gcc` instead.